# Hard code Entity Framework connection string

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When I add an Entity Framework Model to a class library, it creates an app.config file where the connection string is stored.

What do I have to do, to bake the connection string into the project output (*.dll)?

Comment: Why do you want to hardcode connection string? That is the strangest requirement you can have.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka - It makes perfect sense to me.  If everything that DLL is used for uses the same database connection(s) (such as in the case of an internal application), that connection is rarely, if ever, going to change, and you don't want to have to include the connection string in the app.config of every app you build, then hardcoding it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @Bobson: *rarely if ever* that is all I need to know to make it **configurable** without recompiling assembly.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka - Personally, I'd choose recompiling one assembly (which is constantly being modified and redeployed anyway) and deploying it to 20 projects over modifying 20 project's app.config files.  It's definitely situation-dependant, though, and there's plenty of cases when it would be a bad idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store it in a constant or compute it in a variable `dbConnect`, then pass into the constructor.

```
MyDatabaseEntities = new MyDatabaseEntities(dbConnect);
```

Comment: For a code sample of this, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44122708/hard-coding-the-connection-string-in-entity-framework