# Hard Coding the Connection String in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I know that a lot of people think it is a bad idea to hard code connection info but I have a specific situation where I need to do it.  Please don't downtick me because you think this is a bad idea - again, very specific circumstance.

Using the code below, I get the following error on the LINQ statement:  The underlying provider failed on Open.  I have tested the connection string independently and I have no trouble connecting with it.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
       InitializeComponent(); 

        var entityConnectionStringBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
        entityConnectionStringBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
        entityConnectionStringBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-A43456\\MAIN;Initial Catalog=MAIN;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=AppUser;Password=3092409SALFKJ93LK342";
        entityConnectionStringBuilder.Metadata = "res://*";


        MyEntities CustContext = new MyEntities(entityConnectionStringBuilder.ToString());

        var q = (from i in CustContext.Customers
                 where i.fid3 == 15
                 select new CustClass
                 {
                     fid1 = i.fid1,
                     fid2 = i.fid2,
                     fid3  = (int)i.fid3
                 }).ToList<CustClass>();

    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help and insight you can provide.  I did look at other relevant posts and tried various changes on Metadata but they did not work.

Comment: Read the InnerException.

Comment: You need Multiple Active Result Sets

Comment: Could you show us the constructor of `MyEntities`?

Comment: *Please* tell me you didn't just post the actual credentials in your connection string. At least replace them with something generic to get the point across like "someuser" and "somepassword".

Comment: @Brunner   public partial class Entities : DbContext
    {
        public Entities(string nameOrConnectionString)
            : base("name=Entities")
        {
        }

Comment: @SLaks  "Unable to load the specified metadata resource."

Comment: @itsme86 - lol - no those are not real credentials!!!

Comment: @Missy I was afraid of that, it should read `public Entities(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString) {}`

Comment: @Brunner -- Yay!  You fixed it.  Please write that in an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the class definition you've shared in the comments, your problem lies with the `Entities` class.

Its constructor should pass the connection string to the DbContext base class constructor:

```
public Entities(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString) {}
```

All the best with your project!